# php-phantomjs: how to enable disk cache

Tags: php, phantomjs, headless-browser

Although phantomjs has a `disk-cache` option that works when running via command line, when I use [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) no disk caching is created.
Is there any specific setting I should set on PHP or Apache so that php-phantomjs uses disk-cache?

Answer (score 1):

Think I found out how to answer my own question:

1. Make sure that Apache user's home is writable by the user running Apache, or at least that `$HOME/.qws` is writable by that user.
2. Set `$HOME` enviroment variable on PHP script:
   `$apacheUserData = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());
   putenv('HOME='.$apacheUserData['dir']);`

With the above steps `phantomjs` binary running from PHP knows how to find Apache's user dir and is also able to write to `$HOME/.qws`.